# Remove invalid email format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, validation, function, email-validation

```
Array (
    [0] => myemail@domain.com
    [1] => mysecondemail@domain.com
    [2] => invalidEmail.com
)
```

Notice that the third array value is invalid email format. How do I remove it by using/creating a function? I need the valid email to `implode("," the valid email)` before sending an email using the `mail()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$len=count($array);
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
  if (preg_match('^[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)$/i',$array[$i]))
      echo $array[$i];
?>
```

Comment: +1 This is for basic validation only. Addresses with IPv6 as domain part or escaped special characters in username part can't pass this validation. E.g. `alex@2dc0:34::ff92:8ff`, `abc\@xyz@something.com`, etc. To provide accurate e-mail validation you need more than one regex, right?

Comment: While this is not wrong per se (well, I *assume* at least, not having bothered to decipher this Regex), you should use the built-in [filters](http://php.net/filter), which are easier to read and maintain and probably more accurate. Note that AFAIK the PHP email filter doesn't pass all the obscure RFC specs either though.

Comment: thanks for reply. I come out with the new function function getValidEmail($array) {

 $s = 0;
 $arr = null;
 $len = count($array);
 for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
   if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is',$array[$i])) {
    $arr[$s++] = trim($array[$i]);
   }
  
    }
   return $arr;
}

Answer (score 12):

```
$valid = array_filter($emails, create_function('$s', 'return filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);'));
```

Or for PHP 5.3+:

```
$valid = array_filter($emails, function ($s) { return filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution is simple and doesn't require regex

```
  $isvalid = filter_var('myname@anydomain.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

But...

### One line solution just doesn't exist (using regex or something else).

To learn more about valid e-mail addresses, follow references below.

**References:**

- [RFC 821: SIMPLE MAIL TRANSFER PROTOCOL](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt)
- [RFC 822: STANDARD FOR THE FORMAT OF ARPA INTERNET TEXT MESSAGES](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)
- [RFC 1123: Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Application and Support](http://www.remote.org/jochen/rfc/rfc1123.txt)
- [RFC 2142: MAILBOX NAMES FOR COMMON SERVICES, ROLES AND FUNCTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142)
- [RFC 2821: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)](http://www.remote.org/jochen/rfc/rfc2821.txt) - replaced with RFC 821
- [RFC 2822: Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) - replaced with RFC 822
- [RFC 3696: Application Techniques for Checking and Transformation of Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696)
- [RFC 5233: Sieve Email Filtering: Subaddress Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233)
- [RFC 5321: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)
- [RFC 5322: Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
- [RFC 5335: Internationalized Email Headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335)

Some valid examples are:

- 甲斐@黒川.日本
- Rδοκιμή@παράδειγμα
- Pelé@example.com
- jsmith@[192.168.2.1]
- abc@xyz@domain.com

Those addreses are not compilant with [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) standard, but they are still valid.

Even you validate some addresses as correct, nothing can guarantee that your e-mail server will accept them.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody in the real world is really compliant with all these specs. :-( As such, in the context of this question, "valid email" simply means *"subset of RFC specs commonly assumed to be valid email addresses and actually used in real life"*. While I agree that one should strive to be fully RFC compliant when validating emails to avoid further deterioration of the current state of affairs, it seems to be almost impossible to build or find such a validator.

Comment: @deceze, I absolutely agree with you. I also use basic validation on my websites (+IPv4 and IPv6 as domain part are allowed). I know very few people that actually uses that kind of addresses, and to be honest, they have a lot of problems because most of mail servers just can't deal with this format.