# How to handle invalide email exception in cakephp?

Tags: email, cakephp

I have a list of array. There are some invalid emails inside an array. i.e:

```
$to = array('sattar.kuet@gmail.com','sas dsad .com');
```

Here sattar.kuet@gmail.com is an valid mail but *sas dsad .com* is not a valid email. So if I want to send email with this recipients ($to) there will be occurred a fatal error for **sas dsad .com**. So How can I ignore these invalid email?

N.B: I am using cakephp 2.6.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CakeEmail` throws `SocketException` if the email address is not well constructed. Just catch the exception and ignore it.

**Option 1: Send multiple emails**

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$to = array('sattar.kuet@gmail.com','sas dsad .com');  

foreach ($to as $emailAddress)  {
    try {
        $email->to($emailAddress);
        $email->send();
    } catch(SocketException $e) {
        //Do nothing  
    }

    $email->reset();
}
```

**Option 2: Send a single email**

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$to = array('sattar.kuet@gmail.com','sas dsad .com');  

foreach ($to as $emailAddress)  {
    try {
        $email->addTo($emailAddress);
    } catch(SocketException $e) {
        //Do nothing  
    }
}

$email->send();
```

See [`CakeEmail::addTo()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakeEmail.html#_addTo).

Comment: $to = array('sattar.kuet@gmail.com','sas dsad .com','kuet.absb@yahoo.com'); in such case invalid email is in middle. So two valid email will be sent without any exception error message by your code. Would you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using a associative array notation. I'm not a huge fan of sending out email to many addresses in the `to:` field . What about iterating the array and sending individual emails? I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all invalid email with following code :

```
<?php
$len=count($array);
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
  if (preg_match('^[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)$/i',$array[$i]))
      echo $array[$i];
?>
```

[Remove invalid email format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738970/remove-invalid-email-format-in-php)

Comment: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '_'